# In which memory segment (code/data segment) class (employee) is stored?

Tags: c++

I tried to find answer of this question on stack overflow & also on google but didn't get.
Please let me know if any correction is required in question or in case of repeated question.

When I calculated size of employee object (emp_obj) & class employee, in both the cases I got 4 bytes.
But I am not sure about class employee, where it will get stored?

```
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

class employee
{
   int employee_id;
  public:
   employee(int id)
   {
     employee_id = id;
   }
};

int main()
{
  employee emp_obj(100);

  cout << "size of class: " << sizeof(employee);  // 4 bytes
  cout << "size of class object (emp_obj): " << sizeof(emp_obj);  // 4 bytes

  return 0;
}
```

Comment: Types are not stored anywhere in memory at runtime. Only their instances = objects are. (Plus static members, but these are not involved in your code.)

Comment: @DanielLangr: This is mostly true, but *bits* of types (e.g. virtual function tables and RTTI data, where applicable) are stored in memory, and debug builds will usually store enough information to interpret the instances. That said, yes, the concept of the "size of a class itself" is not meaningful.

Comment: Most any C++ compiler will get this object stored in the stack frame of the main() function.  It is not supposed to matter, at least not as long as you don't make it so big that it exhausts all stack space.  Try that.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> In which memory segment (code/data segment) class (employee) is stored?

A class is not stored anywhere in the memory of the executing program. <sup>†</sup>

> When I calculated size of employee object (emp_obj) & class employee, in both the cases I got 4 bytes.

`sizeof(T)` for any type `T` shall return the size of an **object** of type `T`. Therefore, given an object `t`  of type `T`, `sizeof t` and `sizeof(T)` measure exactly the same thing.

---

<sup>†</sup> However, some features of some classes, "Run Time Type Information" in particular, do need storage. The C++ standard does not specify where this data is stored.

Comment: Assume  I have this program and loader will load it into memory to prepare for execution, at this time loader will create 5 memory segments (code, data, bss, stack & heap).  As you told it will not stored anywhere even in code??? then how at run time it is giving size of class employee if it is not stored???

Comment: @JitendraRajput I've explained that in the second paragraph.

Comment: @JitendraRajput: From the C++ perspective, there are only three "segments" - 2 sorts of code and one of data. More precisely, there are three non-interchangeable pointer types: to data, to functions, and to member functions. These three do not align with the 5 segments you expect.

Answer (score 4):

You do realize that

```
sizeof(emp_obj)
```

Is equal to

```
sizeof(employee)
```

Both of them checks the size of an `employee` object, which is 4 bytes as it only contains an integer (Regardless of the values it self)

`emp_obj` Will probably be stored in the stack, as of `employee` class, it's a class not an object, so it is not stored any where.

Comment: Please clarify: Both of them checks the size of an employee object???                       Ques1: if I don't create object then how it is calculating size of class employee???             Ques2: Not stored anywhere??? even in code segment

Comment: @JitendraRajput A1: The size is not calculated at runtime at all. The compiler knows the size of all objects (of complete types) and all `sizeof` expressions are compiled into constant values. A2: Not stored anywhere, indeed.

Comment: Further more, the size is calculated just as one would expect. The compiler looks at `employee` object, see its only data member is int , and it knows it size should be 4.

Answer (score 1):

`sizeof(emp_obj)` is the same thing as `sizeof(employee)`.  `sizeof` gives you the size that an object of that type will occupy in memory.

The actual class itself doesn't occupy any memory, only objects consume memory (and even then they might not after optimizations).

As to where the object is actually stored, C++ doesn't care.  All C++ cares about is how the lifetime of the object is manage, automatic vs dynamic storage duration.  These could be implemented in a stack and heap or heap only or stack only, that's up to the implementation to dictate.